# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined error in form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a Registration form that I am using that is based on the form template [here](https://github.com/peredurabefrog/phpSecureLogin/blob/master/register.php). It was working just fine, but I needed it to also add First and Last Name and a Phone Number, so I changed it to this:

```
        <form method="post" name="registration_form" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            First Name: <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' /><br>
            Last Name: <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' /><br>
            Phone: <input type='tel' name='phone' id='phone' /><br>
            Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
            Password: <input type="password"
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/><br>
            Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br>
            <input type="button" 
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.firstname,
                                   this.form.lastname,
                                   this.form.phone,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" /> 
        </form>
```

I also had to tweak the Javascript form to accept the new values, which is now this:

```
function regformhash(form, uid, firstname, lastname, phone, username, email, password, confirmpwd) {
    // Check each field has a value
    if (uid.value == '' || firstname.value == '' || lastname.value == '' || phone.value == '' || email.value == '' || password.value == '' || confirmpwd.value == '') {
        alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
        return false;
    }
```

I am now getting the "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" error on both the Forms page and the Javascript page associated with the "confirmpwd" field. The field is not empty, and the name hasn't changed from the original template, the only thing that changed was that the First and Last Name and Phone was added to the form.

Comment: The number of parameters you are passing to `regformhash` is not equal the number of arguments. `this.form.firstname` becomes `uid` inside the function body, and so on.

Comment: unrelated: When you've got this working, you may want to check the _trimmed_ values against `== ''` e.g. `|| lastname.value.trim() == '' ||` etc (to avoid fields being filled with only spaces)

Comment: @StephenP, yeah, I'm going to add proper validation after I get the fields working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, your function didn't match up. First, You are passing in 8 params, excluding a value for `uid` to a function expecting 9 inputs. Those values ultimately don't line up as you're expecting, thus, when the function is run, `confirmpwd` is undefined, and when you try to get a property of undefined, you get a `"Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"` error.

As `uid` wasn't in the form, and you also weren't validating `username`, I went ahead and assumed that you were trying to validate `username` and updated your function accordingly.

```js
function regformhash(form, firstname, lastname, phone, username, email, password, confirmpwd) {
    // Check each field has a value
    if (username.value == '' || firstname.value == '' || lastname.value == '' || phone.value == '' || email.value == '' || password.value == '' || confirmpwd.value == '') {
        alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="registration_form" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    First Name: <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' /><br>
    Last Name: <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' /><br>
    Phone: <input type='tel' name='phone' id='phone' /><br>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
    Password: <input type="password"
                        name="password" 
                        id="password"/><br>
    Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                name="confirmpwd" 
                                id="confirmpwd" /><br>
    <input type="button" 
            value="Register" 
            onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                            this.form.firstname,
                            this.form.lastname,
                            this.form.phone,
                            this.form.username,
                            this.form.email,
                            this.form.password,
                            this.form.confirmpwd);" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Cool, I thought the uid parameter was supposed to be in there because it was in the original framework I was working off of, but I took it right out and, with a little bit of tweaking, it worked out.

Answer (score -1):

you have forgotten the uid parameter

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking too, but in the template form that I based this off of, there was no uid paramenter declared in the form, but it was in the Javascript file. Here is the Original .js file [link](https://github.com/peredurabefrog/phpSecureLogin/blob/master/js/forms.js). Keep in mind too, that this form did use to work, I tested it and it worked just fine, it just stopped when I added the 3 additional fields. Oh, also, that was the wrong section in the .js file, I am updating it now.

Comment: Ok, I actually just ended up taking the uid parameter out in the .js file, as it didn't seem to be needed. I was initially confused because it was in the original framework, and it did work when the 3 fields I added weren't there.